# Unexpected output when printing the value of a variable using a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int* u = &i;
    printf("%d\n", *(u + 0));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", *u);
}
```

Output is:

```
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But I think it should print `5` 11 times.

Comment: `i`'s value get changed here `for(i=0;i<10;i++)`

Comment: `u` is pointing at `i`, and `i` is your loop variable, so you're just printing each successive value of `i` in the loop.

Comment: any of the commenters ... although this is quite trivial, I still think you should make it an answer, after all, it answers the question ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen no, instead this question should be closed.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the only closing reason I could think of would be a duplicate. If you find one, fine :) Just not understanding a basic language concept is not a valid closing reason, IMHO.

Comment: @FelixPalmen it absolutely is; Stack Overflow is not a language tutorial site. Basic language features are not to be expected to be taught here (there are Google, and also universities for that which impose expensive tuition fees!). The question also fits a couple of default closure reasons well; for example, the "problem cannot be reproduced" one (which I chose, by the way). Since there's no problem or unexpected behavior, there's nothing to reproduce or ask about.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that's just YOUR interpretation, and IBTD. The output doesn't match the OP's expectation and a valid answer will tell him why. With your interpretation, you could close ~80% of questions asked here on any language. BTW, this discussion would better suit *meta* ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Indeed, ~80% of questions on SO may well be trivially-answerable by either RTFM or just by applying common sense and should in fact be closed IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89508/discussion-between-felix-palmen-and-the-paramagnetic-croissant).

Answer (score 2):

As u contains the address of the variable `i` any changes to `i` will be reflected in the value of `*u` . So going through the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int* u = &i;    //u contains the address of i so change in i changes *u
    printf("%d\n", *(u + 0));    //prints the value of i as *u is the value i that is 5
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)    //the value of i changes so does *u.Therefore *u is incremented from 0 to 9 1 at a time.
    printf("%d\n", *u);     //prints the value of *u whch is effectively i
 }
```

Comment: nitpick: not *in the value of `u`* but *in the value of `*u`* .. `u` will stay constant, being just the address of `i`. Also suggest to use backticks for variable names in your text for better readability.

Comment: I am referring to *u when i said value of u.

Comment: Well, the *value of u* is still the *address of i*. It's better to be -- *super precise* here, because obviously the OP didn't understand pointers fully so far.

Comment: Please also change the last comment to something like "prints the value to which u points: i" because the value of `u`
 is something like 0x777ff....